# Comparing user input with tuple value

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

In Python 3, I have a list of tuples containing various records, lets say it's called `alpha_data`. They are laid out as follows:
[('A', 'Apple', 14.5), ('B', 'Banana', 23.4), etc.]

Is there a way a user can input a value similar to the first value of the tuple (e.g. A or B) and the program will check if this value exists and print back the whole nested value if it does?
Example:

`Input: A`

`Output: A Apple 14.5`

Is there also a way it can be modified so the user can input multiple values and it checks and  prints them all? For example:

`Input: A, B`

`Output:`

```
    A Apple 14.5
    B Banana 23.4
```

EDIT: Maybe I need to be a bit clearer. I've got code that gets the input and converts it to a list of multiple entries. I've then got a line which prints the 3 values of the tuple the way I need it. All I need it way to join these two parts together.

Here is my code so far:

```
import shares
portfolio_str=input("Please list portfolio: ")
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.replace(' ','')
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.upper()
portfolio_list= portfolio_str.split(',')
print(portfolio_list)
print()
print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8}'.format('Code', 'Name', 'Price'))
data=shares.EXCHANGE_DATA
for  (code, name, share_value) in data:
    if code == portfolio_list[]:
            print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(code, name, share_value))
    else:
            print("Failure")
```

As you can see I'm using a module called shares containing a list of tuples called EXCHANGE_DATA which is set out like this:

```
 EXCHANGE_DATA = [('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50),
             ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60),
             ('AMP', 'Amp',3.22), 
             ('ANZ', 'Anzbankgrp', 26.25),
             ('ARG', 'Argosy', 12.22),
             ('CEN', 'Contact', 11.22),
             ('CNU', 'Chorus',3.01),
             ('DIL', 'Diligent', 5.3),
             ('DNZ', 'Dnz Property', 2.33),
             ('EBO', 'Ebos', 1.1),
```

Now how do I get it to check against any value in the user input and print any of them?

Comment: Well, can you explain what you have tried so far? Your question does not show any research effort otherwise (-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting a record given some input `"A"` or `"B"` is pretty simple:

```
alpha_data = [('A', 'Apple', 14.5), ('B', 'Banana', 23.4)]

user_input = "A"

[rec for rec in alpha_data if rec[0] == user_input]
Out[4]: [('A', 'Apple', 14.5)]
```

But if your goal is to allow users to access those entries using `"A"`, `"B"` etc., then a `dict` seems like the more sensible solution:

```
alpha_dict = {"A": ("Apple", 14.5), "B": ("Banana", 23.4)}

user_input = "A"

alpha_dict[user_input]
Out[8]: ('Apple', 14.5)
```

Applying these ideas to your actual use case is pretty simple, in your attempt you iterated through the data and tried to find matches in the `portfolio_list` keys, but it's easier to iterate through `portfolio_list` and look for matches in the data:

```
EXCHANGE_DATA = [('AIA', 'Auckair', 1.50),
            ('AIR', 'Airnz', 5.60),
            ('AMP', 'Amp',3.22), 
            ('ANZ', 'Anzbankgrp', 26.25),
            ('ARG', 'Argosy', 12.22),
            ('CEN', 'Contact', 11.22),
            ('CNU', 'Chorus',3.01),
            ('DIL', 'Diligent', 5.3),
            ('DNZ', 'Dnz Property', 2.33),
            ('EBO', 'Ebos', 1.1)]

portfolio_str=input("Please list portfolio: ")
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.replace(' ','')
portfolio_str= portfolio_str.upper()
portfolio_list= portfolio_str.split(',')
```

Enter some user input:

```
Please list portfolio: AIA, ARG
```

Printing code:

```
print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8}'.format('Code', 'Name', 'Price'))
Code   Name                    Price

for code in portfolio_list:
    # This assumes there will only be one record per code
    rec = [rec for rec in EXCHANGE_DATA if rec[0] == code][0]
    # The *rec part is using a neat python feature called
    # tuple unpacking, google it if you're not familiar with it
    print('{:<6} {:<20} {:>8.2f}'.format(*rec))
```

Output:

```
AIA    Auckair                  1.50
ARG    Argosy                  12.22
```

Comment: What happens if the user input is multiple values?

Comment: @jevans: I haven't tried to address multiple values. If you can't figure out how to convert an input like "A, B" into individual values, maybe you should ask a new question, as it's generally better for stackoverflow questions to address one thing at a time.

Comment: @jevans: see my updated answer, it's a pretty simple extension from the original answer.

Comment: it works brilliantly with only one glitch; part of the question specifies that if the 3 digit code entered does not exist in the EXCHANGE_DATA list it is ignored.. if I enter in a bad code now it gives 'list index out of range', how would I fix this?